# Css grid layout with empty column

Tags: angular, css, css-grid

I am new to css grid and I would like to know if it's possible to use it in the following scenario. I would like to create a layout containing 3 columns, and each column containing a button. In some cases, the button from the last column will not displayed (using angular ngif), but I don't want the layout to be changed (even if the last column does not contain anything, it should look the as if it was). How this be achieved?

I've tried creating 3 columns by using `grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(3, auto);` but if the button in the last column is not displayed, all the other buttons are shifted a little to the right.

Comment: what have you tried? post your complete code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the grid template is applied to the direct children so if you have 3 columns you should have 3 direct children.
If you have a ng-if you will have only 2 children when the ng-if evaluates to false therefore I would recommend you to encapsulate this ng-if into another div so that you always have this 3 children even if the last one is empty.

for example:

```
<div class="my-grid">
  <div>column 1</div>
  <div>column 2</div>
  <div>
    <div ng-if="displayColumn3">column 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

hope this makes sense and helps.